# Initial HttpClient Call Taking a Long Time

Tags: c#, httpclient, portable-class-library

I'm using HttpClient to call a remote web service over https from a C# Portable Class Library.  My initial call to the web service is taking approximately 45 seconds.  Subsequent calls take only a second or two.  I do not have similar problems on the initial call when calling the web service from JavaScript.  Is there a way to optimize HttpClient to make the initial call more quickly?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the delay could be the server side. If you are calling a C# web service, the c# web service needs to be JIT compiled on the first call. The first call could take significantly longer than subsequent calls.

To isolate whether it's a server side or client side issue. Use another client (a browser, or launch another instance of your client application) to call that same web service first. Then use your application with HTTPClient to make its "initial" call to see if the 45sec delay is gone.

Comment: Using another client (JavaScript from Chrome) does not include the delay.  I should also add that this is a call over https.

Comment: 1) you still experience the delay in HttpClient after the web service was called by the JavaScript from Chrome client? 2) Your JavaScript client is calling the same URL as the HttpClient and hitting the same parts of the service code? 3) You verified that the 45 seconds is taken up by the HttpClient call and not other parts of your code? If yes to all of the above, can you show us some code?

Comment: I believe the answer to all of your questions is "yes."   When monitoring the call with Fiddler, I see the "Tunnel to" call take a very long time.  Approximately 45 seconds later, the HTTPS call appears and succeeds.  My code to make the call is:

Comment: `var accessToken = "...";
var authHeader = "...";

var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://music.xboxlive.com/1/") };
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authHeader);

var response =httpClient.GetAsync($"content/music/collection/playlists/browse?{accessToken}&maxItems=25").Result;`

Comment: My httprequest using TcpClient <1s, but HttpClient take >20s

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is the `HttpClient` call that takes time? It could be something else. For example: Are you adding `HttpMessageHandler` to your `HttpClient`?

I had similar issue earlier and the root cause we found out was that we were adding a client certificate to validate request. The client certificate was getting loaded from LocalMachine. Now, if there are many parallel requests and you load the certificate each time from the LocalMachine. All your requests will be blocked till the certificate is loaded for a single request. It may not be certificate but something else in your case. But better confirm that it is the actual call that is taking time.

Comment: How can I confirm this?

Comment: Log the actual time taken by your service call vs. other part of your code like creating the HttpClient object etc. This way you will be able to find out the bottleneck and then you can look to work on it,

Comment: The call itself is what is taking a long time.  Looks like it might be negotiation of the SSL connection?  Any ideas for how to diagnose exactly?